# Putting Video Image On HTML

Tags: html, css, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am in the process of learning how to put a video image on a website, similar to airbnb.com, zipkick.com, I have found most of the info I need coding wise but what I want to know is where I can find short videos like this either at a price or for free(*preferred as I am doing this for the knowledge), also what format they need to be in and how to link them into the HTML properly.

Thank you in advance for your help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best platform I've ever came into for buying short videos is [videohive](http://videohive.net/?osr=tn&_ga=1.238002307.226830539.1439193164), you can either have your video download and served locally using HTML5 semantic markup `<vide>` element, which would look like below;

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Or you can find any youtube video, and get it's embedded `Iframe` and have it implemented on your source code, which would look like this;

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QVkDds13AwY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There are 3 major video types that are supported by global browsers which are listed below;

[image]

It's a best practice to have all the formats specified in your code, goes along with a message at the end of your code chunks, so in cases, that browser doesn't recognize the format, it checks for the next, and next, if none of the formats are supported, user will be popped  with the message you've written at the end of your code chunk...

Comment: Would I put the <video> code between a <div> or just as is in the <body>? And when you say have the formats specified, I should have all 3 and then the message?

Comment: You can either have it stand-alone in your <body> section, or you can have it inside a div, yes, specify all 3 formats, and then the message after...

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as copying a youtube link and embed (see below) on your HTML.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QVkDds11GNY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

See this demo.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.videvo.net
You can use these video clips for free but you do have to sign up. Good news its completely free and they don't ask for anything other than your email and name! Hope this helps on your next project!